# get value from list in exact form it was put in

Tags: r

When I put a values in a list, what is a consistent way to retrieve the value in the same form it was put in?

```
list1 <- list('a'=1, 'b'=2)
list2 <- list('a'=11, 'b'=22, 'c'=33)
listOfLists <- list()
listOfLists <- c(listOfLists, list('first' = list1))
listOfLists <- c(listOfLists, list('second' = list2))

list1['a'] + 5 # should be 6
listOfLists['second']['a'] # should be 11
```

I assume I have to wrap those last two calls in some function `f`. Like `f(f(listOfLists['second'])['a'])`. What does `f` need to be?

*Note: In the actual code I'm adding items programmatically, so I want to keep the names as strings to keep the sample applicable.*

**Edit:** The solution, as noted by Gavin is to use double brackets list1['a'] + 5.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but is `list1[['a']] + 5` and `listOfLists[['second']][['a']]` what you are looking for? I.e. `[[` not `[`. The latter (`[`) returns a list containing the selected component whilst `[[` returns what is inside the selected component - i.e. the actual component.

Comment: It worked!!! I always thought the double bracket was only for getting indexed elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is

```
list1[['a']] + 5

> list1[['a']] + 5
[1] 6
```

and

```
listOfLists[['second']][['a']]

> listOfLists[['second']][['a']]
[1] 11
```

what you are looking for?

I.e. `[[` not `[`. The latter (`[`) returns a list containing the selected component whilst `[[` returns what is inside the selected component - i.e. the actual component.